# vb.net - performance implications of implementing a generic type and a delegate in a function

Tags: .net, vb.net

I wrote a serializer (to Byte Array) for dictionaries that have a string key, but an object of some sort as its value.

I've never implemented a generic type in a function or used a delegate before, so I'm a bit concerned about this being significantly slower than writing a serialization function for a specific type of Dictionary (Dictionary(Of String, MyClass) for example).

Should this code be significantly slower due to the use of the generic type or the delegate?

```
Public Delegate Function Serializer(Of T)(ByRef Obj As T) As Byte()

Function SerializeDictionary_String_Object(Of T)(ByRef D As Dictionary(Of String, T), ByVal S As Serializer(Of T)) As Byte()

    Dim OBJ As T

    For Each X In D
        OBJ = X.Value
        Exit For
    Next

    Return S(OBJ)

End Function
```

Here's some code that uses this:

```
SerializeDictionary_String_Object(Of MyClass)(MyDictionary, AddressOf MyClass.Serialize)
```

It works, and I could loop it and compare it to a more static Dictionary serializer, but I'm more concerned about when I start using this for a lot of different String/Object dictionary combinations, and it'll take me a long time to write a bunch of static dictionary serializers (that's what I'm hoping to avoid in the first place)

edit: simplified intro text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, generics were specifically designed to make code *faster*.  Just as fast as hard-coding the types.  Quicker than the alternative, using Object, since you can avoid boxing value types and don't have to cast.

A delegate call is slower than a direct method call.  But it is still very, very fast.  You'd have to call it a billion times to notice the difference.

Are you aware of the BinaryFormatter class?  It already does this.

Comment: It is my understanding that the BinaryFormatter class uses a slower, generic style of serializing. Thanks for the answer!